# Chrome scales image wrong with Css-element-queries

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

When resizing the window in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/fuzxqkmz/4/ the image (its container) is resized and the image rescales according to that.

The resizing is made by Css-element-queries (https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries)

```
DIV[max-width~="669px"] {
  height: 10.7em;
  left: 14.6em;
}
```

Only in Chrome the image is not scaled correctly. Does anyone know how this could be fixed? `width: auto` and `height: auto` can't be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was accepted as bug for Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677942

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want the `img` to have the height of the parent `div` and the width to be calculated automatically.

So give the `img` a height of `100%`.

https://jsfiddle.net/9pmLk0ft/1/

```
IMG {
  margin-left: 1.2em;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

DIV {
  left: 20.6em;
  height: 21.4em;
}

DIV[max-width~="669px"] {
  height: 10.7em;
  left: 14.6em;
}
```

Comment: I edited the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/fuzxqkmz/4/ height: 100% can't be used as this will make images that are lower bigger (like the "test" image)

Comment: that's a different problem. use `height:100%;` combined with `max-height:xxx;` where xxx is the real height of the image.

Comment: There can be many different images with different heights - so the height is not known

Comment: Ok, then I think you should determine the height of each image on the server side or by using javascript